# Webpack Error in React: Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, game-engine

At the start of one of my files I got these codes:

```
module utilities from "../library/utilities";
module display from "../library/display";
module collision from "../library/collision";
module interactive from "../library/interactive";
module sound from "../library/sound";
module tween from "../library/tween";
```

However in my react app I am getting the following error which does not make sense:

> Failed to compile.
>
> Error in ./src/game_book/library/engine.js Syntax error: Unexpected
>   token, expected ; (2:7)

As you can see there is no comma (,) in the line with error there.....

Also as far as I can tell that is the right path to utilities.js

This is the github repository of the sample code I'm trying to use:

https://github.com/Apress/adv-game-design-w-html5-javascript/blob/master/library/engine.js

What's going on?
How to fix?

Comment: what is the code in the file from line 2 ?, Edit: I guess you wanted "import name from path"

Comment: import does not work the same...but why does modeule...not work?

Comment: I do not recall anything about this usage of module keyword. Are you sure you are using it correctly?

Comment: It is from a book.  I personally don't use the keyword module too....

Comment: could it be related to traceur?

Comment: I found the git repository for the sample code from book I'm using  https://github.com/Apress/adv-game-design-w-html5-javascript/blob/master/library/engine.js